# Circular Dependency Error While Loading an ASDF System

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I'm trying to get a first program to load with ASDF under SBCL on Windows: `(asdf:load-system "dependencies")`. ASDF is able to find the directory and .asd file, but produces a warning and an error:

```
* (asdf:load-system "dependencies")
WARNING: System definition file #P"C:/Users/davyp/AppData/Local/lxss/root/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-ppcre-20190521-git/cl-ppcre.asd" contains definition for system "cl-ppcre-test". Please only define "cl-ppcre" and secondary systems with a name starting with "cl-ppcre/" (e.g. "cl-ppcre/test") in that file.
WARNING:
   Deprecated recursive use of (ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE 'ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP
   '("dependencies")) while visiting
   (ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP "dependencies" "dependencies") - please use proper
   dependencies instead

debugger invoked on a ASDF/ACTION:CIRCULAR-DEPENDENCY in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10010B0523}>:
  Circular dependency:
     ((#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP >
       . #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "dependencies" "dependencies">)
      (#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP > . #<ASDF/SYSTEM:SYSTEM "dependencies">))

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [TRY-RECOMPILING              ] Recompile dependencies and try loading it again
  1: [RETRY                        ] Retry
                                     loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "dependencies" "dependencies">.
  2: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating
                                     loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "dependencies" "dependencies">
                                     as having been successful.
  3:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  4: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  5:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  6:                                 Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  7: [ABORT                        ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/ACTION:CALL-WHILE-VISITING-ACTION))
   error finding frame source: Bogus form-number: the source file has probably
                               changed too much to cope with.
   source: NIL
0]
```

My .conf file contains the single entry: `(:directory #P"D:/Users Data/Dave/SW Library/AI/Dependencies/")`; and here is the defsystem from the .asd file:

```
(defsystem "dependencies"
  :description "dependencies: A Common Lisp system for detecting ~
                inter-dependencies between a project's files."
  :version "1"
  :author "David Brown <davypough@gmail.com>"
  :licence "Public Domain"
  :depends-on ("alexandria" "cl-ppcre")
  :components ((:file "dependencies")))  ;ie, dependencies.lisp
```

For the warning, it looks like ASDF is finding cl-ppcre associated with another program, even though the registry was first cleared with `(asdf:clear-source-registry)`. The error seems to relate to a circularity of some kind. Thanks for any assistance sorting things out.

Comment: Does "dependencies.lisp" invoke quicklisp or asdf?

Comment: @coredump Awk! Thanks for making me carefully check dependencies.lisp (extra line with asdf:load-system). Should I delete this post? Still have the warning about cl-ppcre though.

Comment: I don't know, maybe someone will have a better answer for the ppcre part, the warning is mostly intended for the developers of cl-ppcre, there is not much you can do as a user of the library :/

Comment: Good thing you didn't delete this question. Saved my skin!